# Running Local Stack and a Lambda service (Image?) within a single docker compose file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface, localstack

As part of my own development, I am attempting to run my entire personal project within a single docker compose file and am struggling to add my Local Stack SQS as an event source to my Lambda service.

The flow I'm struggling with is:
ReactApp --> Java Service --> AWS SNS --> AWS SQS --> Java Lambda

Everything works well up until the AWS SQS. If I use the AWS CLI to receive the messages from the SQS, I can see they exist. I can then use that as input to a HTTP GET request and can call the Lambda directly. However, I'm struggling to see how to use the AWS CLI / Local Stack / Docker to configure my Lambda service as an event source to the SQS. I think the issue is that Local Stack isn't aware of the Lambda service and it therefore, it doesn't have an ARN reference for me to use in another CLI command within `setup-resources`

Extract of my docker-compose file is shown below. The `proclubsleague-lambda` is built using `FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:17`

```
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs,sns,lambda
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
      - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=true
      - LAMBDA_REMOVE_CONTAINERS=true
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - DEBUG=1
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "53:53"
      - "443:443"
      - "4510-4520:4510-4520"
      - "4566-4620:4566-4620"
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
    - localstack    
  setup-resources:
    image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    command: |
      "
        sleep 20
        aws --endpoint-url=http://host.docker.internal:4566 sns create-topic --name proclubsfa-sns.fifo --region eu-west-2 --output table --attributes FifoTopic=true,ContentBasedDeduplication=false

        echo '{\"FifoQueue\": \"true\",\"ContentBasedDeduplication\": \"false\"}' > sqs.json
        aws --endpoint-url=http://host.docker.internal:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name proclubsfa-sqs.fifo --region eu-west-2 --output table --attributes file://sqs.json
    
        aws --endpoint-url=http://host.docker.internal:4566 sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:000000000000:proclubsfa-sns.fifo --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:000000000000:proclubsfa-sqs.fifo --output table
      "
    depends_on:
      - localstack
    networks:
      - localstack
  proclubsleague-lambda:
    image: XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/proclubsleague-lambda:latest
    ports: 
      - "9000:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
    - localstack
networks:
  localstack:
    external: false
    driver: bridge
    name: localstack
```

I'm fairly new to all of this. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: (Do you _have_ to use AWS-specific technologies here?  Instead of SQS, can you use an open-source messaging system like RabbitMQ or Kafka; and instead of AWS Lambda, can you use a long-running worker container?  Spring Cloud Streams might be a good match for this setup.)

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the reply. 
Technically no, its for my personal project so the focus is on learning. However, I would like to stick to the current architecture.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to have the lambda function outside of LocalStack, as a separate image? If you are able to deploy your lambda using a managed runtime, I would suggest using the LocalStack lambda functionality to deploy your archive directly. I think if you want to use an image based Lambda, you will need the Pro version of LocalStack. LocalStack cannot invoke the function you start in another container by yourself, as you seem to try.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up resolving this by creating a proclubsleague-lambda.jar and adding more commands to deploy the lambda to the LocalStack instance :)